# Get all xhr request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get all xhr status 200 and their information when completed. It is possible to get them together in some way or I would have to keep a reference to each of them when i send?

Comment: The easiest way would be to keep a reference to them, my suggestion is that you use an array and an asynchronous semaphore. The easiest way might be to use a promise library or built in. What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: jQuery's `ajaxComplete` will give you a generic way to handle the response you get from each of your request.

Comment: look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/),

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        //rest of the handler
    }
});
```

This will ensure all your ajax responses will hit this method when they're complete, an extra check will be required for the status of the response.

Comment: with that i only get the requests done by jquery. What i want is to retrive all the request.

Comment: What other method are you using to implement ajax?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using asp.net then you can add Application_EndRequest method in your global.asax file and check the response.